# Why can "bill" mean (almost) opposite things?

Tags: meaning, etymology, antonyms, auto-antonyms

*Bill* is somewhat of an [auto-antonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym), since it can mean either a piece of paper which has positive monetary value (i.e. a *note*), or a piece of paper which has negative monetary value (though it only applies to a certain person).  Maybe I'm reading too much into the usages, but it seems strange that the two meanings of *bill* are nearly opposite.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Note that the *note* meaning of *bill* is chiefly American: we would say *five-dollar bill* but not *five-pound bill* (and *five-pound note* but not *five-dollar note*).

Comment: Any money owed by one entity is owed to another entity. Possibly the term originated before paper currency became as common as it is today.

Comment: I don't think "autantonym" (aka "contronym") is a particularly useful term. The current case  *bill=money/debt* is like *weather=endure/erode*. Two different meanings of a single root word diverge so much they can be seen as opposites. In other cases, like *cleave=split/adhere*, two different words just happen to have the same spelling. Interesting quirks of language, but I can't see why we need *two* technical terms for something so trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without doing too much research into this, the [etymology of bill](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bill) shows that the original usage was more like an official document at first.

> "written statement," mid-14c., from Anglo-L. billa "list," from M.L. bulla "decree, seal, sealed document,"

This suggests that different people adopted the word to mean similar, but related, concepts. In fact, government currency is a form of money owed, in that (in the days of the [Gold Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_standard)) the government promised you the bill's face value in gold. Now it is more abstract but the terms are related, even if seemingly opposite.

Comment: So, in short, *bill (note):government:me::bill (invoice):me:servicer* -- Is that right?

Comment: @drɱ65δ: yes, that is what I was trying to say. But I don't have something definitive to say if that is an intentional or coincidental overlap.

Answer (score 3):

In general, this situation can arise for two main reasons:

(1) a word that originally meant a narrower concept diversifies to cover related concepts or specific connotations, and gradually over time the precise meanings of these once strongly related concepts can further diverge over time;

(2) what were once two separate words could merge due to sound changes or other phonological processes.

In this case, as mentioned in the answer above, it appears that effectively situation (1) has arisen: "bill" expanded from its original meaning of "official document" to cover various different specific connotations of "document" today, be it the "bill" put up by a "bill poster", the "bill" you pay for your meal, a "bill" of rights, a "dollar bill" etc.

Answer (score 0):

A "bill" is an evidence the party A owes money to party B.

The "bill" that arrives in the mail from say, the phone company, is evidence that you owe money to the phone company.

A "bill" in the currency sense, is evidence that the government owes money to you. If you give the bill (instead of writing a check) to the phone company, the government then owes money to the phone company.

(This came about because "money" used to be gold and silver. In the U.S. the 16th Amendment to the Constitution gave the Federal government the authority to issue paper money as a substitute for metal. So (most people turned in their gold and silver and received paper "bills" (IOUs) in return.